# group messages - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `messages` that stores user messages, and the table structure looks like this:

Messages:

```
id   from_id    to_id  content
1    1          2       ABC
2    2          1       BCC
3    1          2       EFG
1    4          2       GHJ
2    2          4       MNX
3    15         2       LKH
```

Is it possible to run a query to group messages like the following?

Expected Output:

```
   from_id  to_id    
    1       2               
    4       2           
    15      2
```

Conversation between two parties will be in one group. So, we can see from table `messages`, there are 3 groups.

Comment: Should (1,2) and (2,1) wind up in the same group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(from_id, to_id) from_id, 
                GREATEST(from_id, to_id) to_id
  FROM messages;
```

Output:

```
| FROM_ID | TO_ID |
|---------|-------|
|       1 |     2 |
|       2 |     4 |
|       2 |    15 |
```

or

```
SELECT from_id, to_id
  FROM messages
 GROUP BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), 
          GREATEST(from_id, to_id);
```

Output:

```
| FROM_ID | TO_ID |
|---------|-------|
|       1 |     2 |
|       4 |     2 |
|      15 |     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/740c3/3)** demo

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_id, to_id
FROM messages
WHERE to_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come with the following solution. We `LEFT` join the messages with responses. Then, we select distinct pairs of `from_id` and `to_id`, but we use `CASE` expression to decide if we'll take the `from_id` and `to_id` from the first message, or a response. This is based on an assumption that it is ok to always have a smaller id as `from_id` and larger id in `to_id`.

Solution:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INT,
    from_id INT,
    to_id INT,
    content VARCHAR(20)
);


INSERT INTO messages VALUES (1, 1, 2, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (2, 2, 1, 'BCC');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (3, 1, 2, 'EFG');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (1, 4, 2, 'GHJ');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (2, 2, 4, 'MNX');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (3, 15, 2, 'LKH');

SELECT
    DISTINCT
      CASE
        WHEN m2.from_id IS NULL
          OR m1.from_id < m2.from_id THEN m1.from_id
        ELSE m2.from_id
      END AS from_id,
      CASE
        WHEN m2.to_id IS NULL
          OR m1.to_id > m2.to_id THEN m1.to_id
        ELSE m2.to_id
      END AS to_id
  FROM
    messages m1
    LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.from_id = m2.to_id AND m1.to_id = m2.from_id)
;
```

```
FROM_ID    TO_ID
1          2
2          4
15         2
```

[Check at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75edb3/4)